# Autofoo test for maximum version of Python

Tags: build, autoconf, automake, gnu-toolchain, linux-toolchain

I'm trying to get autofoo to test for a *maximum* version of Python rather than a minimum.  Example:

```
AC_REQUIRE([AM_PATH_PYTHON([2.7])])
```

... will test for Python >= 2.7, and will probably turn up with /usr/bin/python3. I want it to return nothing greater than python2.7, however.

Is there a straightforward way to do this? I asked around, and so far the best response I've gotten is, "rewrite the macro."

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm afraid your best response so far is probably right. Isn't it just a question of copying the macro and changing `-gt` to `-lt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1). Add to `acinclude.m4`

```
`# my_CHECK_MAJOR_VERSION(VARIABLE, VERSION, [ACTION-IF-TRUE], [ACTION-IF-FALSE])`  
`# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------`  
`# Run ACTION-IF-TRUE if the VAR has a major version >= VERSION.`  
`# Run ACTION-IF-FALSE otherwise.`  
AC_DEFUN([my_CHECK_MAJOR_VERSION],  
[AC_MSG_CHECKING([whether $1 $$1 major version == $2])  
case $$1 in  
$2*)  
  AC_MSG_RESULT([yes])  
  ifelse([$3], [$3], [:])  
  ;;  
*)  
  AC_MSG_RESULT([no])  
  ifelse([$4], , [AC_MSG_ERROR([$$1 differs from $2])], [$4])  
  ;;  
esac])
```

2.) Add to `zconfigure.inz`

```
my_CHECK_MAJOR_VERSION([PYTHON_VERSION], [2])
```

3.) `aclocal`, `automake`, `autoconf`

That's it.

Answer (score 2):

The version argument to `AM_PATH_PYTHON` is optional. If python is required, call it like this:

```
AM_PATH_PYTHON
```

If it's not required, call it like this:

```
AM_PATH_PYTHON(,, [:])
```

Now, `AM_PATH_PYTHON` sets the shell variable `$PYTHON_VERSION` to the value of `sys.version[:3]`, which you can test yourself.

Comment: Right, the issue is that if there are multiple installations of Python on the system, e.g., 2.7 and 3.0, I want $PYTHON_VERSION to become 2.7, and have the rest of the vars reflect that binary path, etc.,

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that bit. Even though it doesn't show up in `./configure --help`, you can set `$PYTHON` using something like `./configure PYTHON=/usr/bin/python2.7`.

Comment: Apparently allowing the user to set `$PYTHON` is the correct behaviour, see the bug report here: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-automake/2011-01/msg00105.html . It works fine on current automake, but future versions will add help information to `./configure --help`. So you should be fine to test against the result of `AM_PATH_PYTHON` and direct the user to provide an alternate `$PYTHON` if their system version is too new.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution can be setting the default for [_AM_PYTHON_INTERPRETER_LIST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19173018/1207160), to include only Python 2 binaries.